# How to write multiple total in different rows in tabulation for mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0.

Here's my sample database:

```
create table test_area (
ref int,
b varchar(3),
c varchar(3),
d varchar(3),
e varchar(3),
bcde varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (ref)
);

insert into test_area (ref,b,c,d,e,bcde) values (1,'01','00','00','00','Superheroes');
insert into test_area (ref,b,c,d,e,bcde) values (2,'01','01','00','00','Marvel');
insert into test_area (ref,b,c,d,e,bcde) values (3,'01','01','01','00','X-Men');
insert into test_area (ref,b,c,d,e,bcde) values (4,'01','01','01','01','Wolverine');
insert into test_area (ref,b,c,d,e,bcde) values (5,'01','01','01','02','Gambit');
insert into test_area (ref,b,c,d,e,bcde) values (6,'01','01','02','00','Avengers');
insert into test_area (ref,b,c,d,e,bcde) values (7,'01','01','02','01','Ironman');
insert into test_area (ref,b,c,d,e,bcde) values (8,'01','02','00','00','DC');
insert into test_area (ref,b,c,d,e,bcde) values (9,'01','02','01','00','Justice League');
insert into test_area (ref,b,c,d,e,bcde) values (10,'01','02','01','01','Supeman');
insert into test_area (ref,b,c,d,e,bcde) values (11,'01','02','01','02','Batman');

create table test_data (
b varchar(3),
c varchar(3),
d varchar(3),
e varchar(3),
data int
);

insert into test_data (b,c,d,e,data) values ('01','01','01','01',1);
insert into test_data (b,c,d,e,data) values ('01','01','01','01',2);
insert into test_data (b,c,d,e,data) values ('01','01','01','02',3);
insert into test_data (b,c,d,e,data) values ('01','01','02','01',4);
insert into test_data (b,c,d,e,data) values ('01','02','01','01',0);
insert into test_data (b,c,d,e,data) values ('01','02','01','02',5);
insert into test_data (b,c,d,e,data) values ('01','02','02','02',6);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jYQJPV1X1XPbLp72LqA5CZ/11

Expected Output:

```
DESCRIPTION          | DATA
Superheroes            21
  Marvel               10
    X-men              6
      Wolverine        3
      Gambit           3
    Avengers           4
      Ironman          4
  DC                   5
    Justice League     5
      Superman         0
      Batman           5
  Not on the List      6
```

I just want to have my table to have a total for each class. I just put an indention in the table to be easily identified in which class it belongs to. Also, the data that was not in the description will be counted as "not on the list".

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: based on my example, there will be no primary key.

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then in a strict sense you don't really have a table which, I'd argue, puts the question beyond the scope of an rdbms tag.

Comment: My primary key here supposedly the 'ref' of test_area. Unfortunately, I did not notice that it was not unique. I would change the 1st row of the table into code '0' to be a primary key.

Comment: Please edit your question (and fiddle) accordingly

Comment: This 'ref' of test_area was just an incremental value.

Answer (score 0):

If appropriate, I'd be tempted to start with a different model - either an edge/adjaceny list or a nested set, rather than this sort of hybrid materialized path.

Here's an (incomplete) example using a nested set model:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS comic_tree;

CREATE TABLE comic_tree
( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
, entity_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE
, lft INT NOT NULL 
, rgt INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO comic_tree (id,lft,entity_name,rgt) VALUES
( 1, 1,'Superheroes',22),
( 2, 2,'Marvel',13),
( 3, 3,'X-Men',8),
( 4, 4,'Wolverine',5),
( 5, 6,'Gambit',7),
( 6, 9,'Avengers',12),
( 7,10,'Ironman',11),
( 8,14,'DC',21),
( 9,15,'Justice League',20),
(10,16,'Superman',17),
(11,18,'Batman',19);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS comic_product;

CREATE TABLE comic_product
( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
, comic_tree_id INT NULL
, qty INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO comic_product(comic_tree_id,qty) VALUES
( 4,1),
( 4,2),
( 5,3),
( 7,4),
(11,5),
(NULL,6);


SELECT x.id
     , x.entity_name 
     , SUM(y.qty) total 
  FROM comic_tree x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN comic_product y 
    ON y.comic_tree_id = x.id 
 GROUP
    BY x.id 
 UNION 
SELECT NULL
     , 'Others'
     , SUM(qty) 
  FROM comic_product 
 WHERE comic_tree_id IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY entity_name = 'Others'
     , id;

+----------------+-------+
| entity_name    | total |
+----------------+-------+
| Superheroes    |  NULL |
| Marvel         |  NULL |
| X-Men          |  NULL |
| Wolverine      |     3 |
| Gambit         |     3 |
| Avengers       |  NULL |
| Ironman        |     4 |
| DC             |  NULL |
| Justice League |  NULL |
| Superman       |  NULL |
| Batman         |     5 |
| Others         |     6 |
+----------------+-------+
```

Extending this idea...

```
SELECT a.*
     , COALESCE(b.total,0) total
  FROM
     ( SELECT node.id
            , CONCAT( REPEAT(' ', COUNT(parent.entity_name) - 1), node.entity_name) entity_name
         FROM comic_tree node
         JOIN comic_tree parent  
        WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        GROUP 
           BY node.id
        ORDER 
           BY node.lft
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT parent.id
            , parent.entity_name
            , SUM(comic_product.qty) total
         FROM comic_tree node 
         JOIN comic_tree parent
           ON node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
         JOIN comic_product 
           ON comic_product.comic_tree_id = node.id 
        GROUP 
           BY parent.id
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id
 ORDER 
    BY a.id;
    
    +----+------------------+-------+
    | id | entity_name      | total |
    +----+------------------+-------+
    |  1 | Superheroes      |    15 |
    |  2 |  Marvel          |    10 |
    |  3 |   X-Men          |     6 |
    |  4 |    Wolverine     |     3 |
    |  5 |    Gambit        |     3 |
    |  6 |   Avengers       |     4 |
    |  7 |    Ironman       |     4 |
    |  8 |  DC              |     5 |
    |  9 |   Justice League |     5 |
    | 10 |    Superman      |     0 |
    | 11 |    Batman        |     5 |
    +----+------------------+-------+
```

I'll leave the task of incorporating 'Others' into the above, as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I am kinda confused with the values. how did you come up with those? my example was just a superhero with data. This will be grouped according to its kind based on the test_area. It was just like Earth, Continent, Country, up to its smallest disaggregation. Then it should be tabulated according to its class.

Comment: For the earth-continent model you describe , you'd normally have a table of continents, a table of countries, and a table of cities. The city table would have an FK to the country table, and the country table would have an FK to the continent table.

Comment: For how I came up with those values, see Mike Hillyer's excellent (if slightly dated) article on hierarchical data. http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/